# Tengo una excepcion cuando trato de correr mi proyecto y no entiendo porque (Selenium y TestNG)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, test-ng

Tengo la siguiente excepción cuando trato de hacer unas pruebas con selenium usando testng,  pero me dice que tengo una excepción causada por Selenium web driver; según entiendo es por FireFox pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class TestCases.suite
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:166)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:26)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:59)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: firefox
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:96)
    at TestCases.suite.<init>(suite.java:24)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: hi there! welcome to StackOverflow in Spanish! so, could you please translate your question or consider to move it to StackOverflow.com otherwise we are going to close it. Have a nice day!

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés, debería traducirse, especificar mejor en qué parte del código se dispara, y [edit] la pregunta agregando el código antes de que se acepte en [es.so].

Comment: Hola Laura. Este es el sitio en español, considera publicar la pregunta en el idioma español. Asimismo, si solo la deseas mantener en inglés, por favor avisa mediante un reporte o comentario en tu pregunta y será migrada al sitio en inglés.

Comment: Suponiendo que tienes Firefox instalado correctamente en tu equipo, comprueba que estás usando la última versión del driver disponible.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar tu instalacion de firefox, necesitas indicarle donde tienes el webdriver the firefox, son dos cosas diferentes. Necesitas tener instalada una version de firefox, usar una distribucion de selenium y dependiendo de las versiones elegidas hasta este punto, necesitaras un webdriver u otro.

Hasta la version 3.0 de selenium no hacia falta indicar nada, pero si estas en una version posterior necesitas descargar [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) y posteriormente en el codigo antes de iniciar el driver indicar al sistema donde se encuentra, con una linea parecida a esta:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                   "ruta/a/distribuciongecko");
```